Istio failover to external service when internal service is unhealthy
Need to failover/redirect to external service (which is not in Mesh) when internal service is unhealthy (is in Mesh).
External Service - abc.example.com
Internal Service - abc.svc.cluster.local
Tried the following config but the redirection doesn't seem to be working as expected. When I scale down the pods of internal service and send request to "abc.svc.cluster.local", it doesn't redirect to "abc.example.com" - it just keeps on giving me 5xx.
Expected result - Should redirect to "abc.example.com" when "abc.svc.cluster.local" is down.

Created the ServiceEntry for external service

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: external-backend
spec:
  hosts:
  - abc.example.com
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: TLS
  resolution: DNS


Created a DestinationRule that will keep on checking if service is healthy

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: backend-destination-rule
spec:
  host: abc.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    outlierDetection:
      consecutive5xxErrors: 3
      interval: 10s
      baseEjectionTime: 30s


Created VirtualService for redirection

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - abc.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: abc.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
      weight: 100
    retries:
      attempts: 3
      perTryTimeout: 2s
    timeout: 5s
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: abc.example.com
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 0


I believe destination weight of zero will never receive traffic. If the internal and external service will return the same responses put both destinations on the same route with 99 and 1.
Depending on the failure istio should stop sending to a higher weight destination that is failed. Unhealthy is a vague term but if its completely down this may work.
i.e.
- route:
  - destination:
       host: abc.svc.cluster.local
       port:
         number: 80
     weight: 99
  - destination:
      host: abc.example.com
      port:
        number: 443
    weight: 1


@lance.johnsn thanks, tried the suggested config still it is not routing.
